# json parse an object recieved after firing a query in ajax

Tags: jquery, json

I have a structure in my DOM which looks like

```
window>object>payload>records>0>Object { attributes={...}, Id="a0E90K", Name="David", more...}
    ..............................2>Object { attributes={...}, Id="a0E90K", Name="alen", more...}
    ..............................3>Object { attributes={...}, Id="a0E43K", Name="woody", more...}
    ..............................4>Object { attributes={...}, Id="a2341K", Name="mac", more...}
    ..............................5>Object { attributes={...}, Id="a344R7K", Name="fin", more...}
```

where this payload is the result i got after firing a query with ajax.Now how do i get the id and name for the records?

Comment: Can you post your data structure in a clearer format, it's almost unreadable. Also, where is item #1?

Comment: What is the correct JSON format u r getting?

Comment: OMG what is this? (Witchcraft!) Please, post correct format or atleast a part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming the JSON Result from Server is something like

`{"records"=[{"attributes"={[..]}, id="aoEdds", Name="David"},{Rec2Info, etc}]}`

for the above JSON, you can parse the `ajax success callback` like below

```
   success:function(data){
   $.each(data.records,function(i){
     alert($(this).id); // gives id
     alert($(this).Name);
   });
   }
```